# Why does the thread run only once?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to track the position of the mouse cursor and thus need to use a thread to continue tracking it. My thread is running only once. I'm guessing that I have missed something along the way.

The code :

mousePosition class

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Timer;

public class mousePosition implements Runnable
{
    static Point mouseLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    static Timer t = new Timer();
    int x,y = 0;


    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
                x = mouseLocation.x;
                y = mouseLocation.y;

                System.out.println("X:"+x+" Y:"+y+" at time "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception caught : "+e);
        }

    }



}
```

main class

```
public class threadRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new mousePosition());

        t1.start();

    }

}
```

Thank you for any help. I know that this question was asked before but I am still struggling to make it work.

Comment: Since there is no loop and you don't use your timer, it makes sense that the `run` method only runs once.

Comment: Why don't you use your timer in your thread?  The `run()` method of your thread will always return after executing the code and end your thread!!

Comment: You usually have some while statement in a run method in order to keep the thread running, and quite often while true

Comment: I think I might have found a way around it since I know how many times I want to run the thread.

Comment: The reason I have not used the timer is plainly due to lack of experience

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Thread's `run()` method will only run once. It would run much more if you did something like this:

```
public void run() {
  while(true) { // Or with a stop condition
    try {
            x = mouseLocation.x;
            y = mouseLocation.y;

            System.out.println("X:"+x+" Y:"+y+" at time "+System.currentTimeMillis());

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught : "+e);
    }
  }
}
```

Although I'm sure this while loop on a thread is expensive, speaking in computational cost, and there is a better practice using the [Observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). An implementation and example of this good practice, is just precisely the [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html).

Answer (score 2):

When you `start()` a new `Thread`, the only thing that happens is that the `Thread`s `run()` method is executed. Once the `run()` method is finished, the `Thread` dies.

To continually check the mouse position, you should probably start some kind of `MouseListener` instead, there is a nice tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

To learn more about threads, I recommend looking throw the [Java Tutorials on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threads.html).

Comment: ah ok that makes sense.. so is it wise to loop the try code in the run? Because when I did that, it gave me the answer of the same mouse position which also makes sense. I think its a qusetion of where to place the loop

Comment: @alexeidebono: Since you only check the mouse position when the Thread is created, a loop won't do much there. Check out my links for some useful reading.

Comment: @alexeidebono: you must also invoke  `getLocation()` in each loop iteration, otherwise you will return only starting position.

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple way to read mouse position every 50ms

```
class mousePosition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                int x, y;
                try {
                    PointerInfo mouseLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                    x = mouseLocation.getLocation().x;
                    y = mouseLocation.getLocation().y;
                    System.out.println("X:" + x + " Y:" + y + " at time "
                            + System.currentTimeMillis());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception caught : " + e);
                }
            }
        }, 0, 50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this :

```
public void run()
    {
        try
        {       
                boolean mouseTracked = false;
                while(!mouseTracked){
                   x = mouseLocation.x;
                   y = mouseLocation.y;

                System.out.println("X:"+x+" Y:"+y+" at time "+System.currentTimeMillis());
                mouseTracked = true; //do this when mouse tracked..
        }
}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception caught : "+e);
        }

    }
```

this will continue to track the mouse until you set mouseTracked to true, set mouseTracked to true that you will do in a match condition

Answer (score 0):

Change your class like this

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Timer;

public class MousePosition implements Runnable
{
static Point mouseLocation = null;
static Timer t = new Timer();
int x,y = 0;


public void run()
{   
  while(true){
    try
    {
          mouseLocation= MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();

            x = mouseLocation.x;
            y = mouseLocation.y;

            System.out.println("X:"+x+" Y:"+y+" at time "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception caught : "+e);
    }
  }
}
}
```